# What method can be used to obtain a fifth and sixth "bonus feat"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-creation, optimization

The goal is to obtain a total of six feats that clearly have the label of "bonus feat" at first level. The character class is Erudite, which has two first level bonus feats. Taking two flaws grants two more bonus feats.

How can I obtain the last two bonus feats at first level? Is there a race or template which has two features or abilities using the words bonus feat?

Not interested in TOs (theoretical optimizations), or methods which require helper NPCs, or wealth beyond a starting Erudite's Wealth by Level.

Comment: What do you have to play with? I mean, for example, LA +2 and 1 HD (hence ECL +3) yields a werebadger that gets the bonus feats Agile, Iron Will, Track, and Weapon Finesse. Or should the question be limited to ECL +0 templates and races?

Comment: If flaws are allowed, what about other UA material like Gesalts?

Comment: 1 level total only, so no ECL this time. It has to be a first level bonus feat, and hit dice have been established to count as levels. Gestalt... that is a valid point, feel free to include it as part of an answer.

Comment: Are you looking for empty feat slots that can be filled with whatever, or just a way to have the most feats possible at level 1? Both things are very different answers.

Comment: Just two feats that are considered bonus feats.

Answer (score 5):

### Be an Elf

The [Elf](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/races.htm#elves) race has a bunch of "bonus feats", though they are probably not that useful to your character:

> Weapon Proficiency: Elves receive the Martial Weapon Proficiency feats for the longsword, rapier, longbow (including composite longbow), and shortbow (including composite shortbow) as bonus feats.